# how to get bytes loaded to server using rails paperclip gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, paperclip

i am using paperclip gem to upload images on the server side, i need to get updated with the bytes loaded on server through the upload process.

my aim is to update the progress bar accordingly.  how do I do this?

Comment: Please take a look at this [uploadify-with-paperclip-on-rails-tutorial](http://fencore.posterous.com/uploadify-with-paperclip-on-rails-tutorial). I think your question title should be something like "Progress bar on paperclip". Then it's easier to understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do this by using a Flash-based uploading tool which has direct access to the file and the upload stream.  Just integrate it with Paperclip (and there are a ton of examples on google showing how to)

I would recommend one of these:

http://plupload.com/

http://www.uploadify.com/